# Salesforce CPQ quote Template

Tags: cpq

I want to display Features and Options related to the product on my Quote template, but I am not sure how to display those records in Salesforce CPQ quote Template without using visualforce as Template Content.

Answer (score 0):

If a product option is selected, it should show up as a Quote Line that you can conditionally filter.

If you're trying to show all available options, you don't have any other choice than to use the Visualforce sections